# Why am I getting an "Uncaught (in promise)" error while using rosbag.js to open a bag file

Tags: javascript, ros, rosbag

I'm trying to open and parse bag file. Using the code below.

```
window.setImmediate = window.setTimeout;

import { open } from 'rosbag';

const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
function handleFiles() {
    const fileList = this.files;
    console.log(fileList[0]);
    const bag = open(fileList[0]);
}
```

The file selection and the `console.log(filelist[0])` seems Ok.

But then I get in the console:

> index.ts:66 Uncaught (in promise)
> Uint8Array(13) [35, 82, 79, 83, 66, 65, 71, 32, 86, 50, 46, 48, 10, buffer: ArrayBuffer(13), byteLength: 13, byteOffset: 0, length: 13, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8Array']
> open @ index.ts:66
> await in open (async)
> handleFiles @ rosbag_load_example.js?t=1690294141697:59
> Show 1 more frame